# Projection of vector onto another vector alternate equation

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis

The projection of vector $\mathbf a$ onto vector $\mathbf v$ is given by $$ \left( \frac {\mathbf a \cdot \mathbf v} {\left\lVert \mathbf v^2 \right\rVert} \right) \mathbf v$$

This seems like a roundabout way to solve the problem. Can't the projection of vector $\mathbf a$ onto vector $\mathbf v$ simply be given by $$ \left( \frac {\mathbf a \cdot \mathbf v} {\left\lVert \mathbf v \right\rVert} \right)$$ Since,

$$ \left( \frac {\mathbf a \cdot \mathbf v} {\left\lVert \mathbf v \right\rVert} \right) = \left( \frac {\left\lVert \mathbf a \right\rVert\left\lVert \mathbf v \right\rVert \cos \theta} {\left\lVert \mathbf v \right\rVert} \right) = \left\lVert \mathbf a \right\rVert \cos \theta$$ where $\theta$ is the angle between vector $\mathbf a$ and vector $\mathbf v$?

If so, can it be claimed that $$ \left( \frac {\mathbf a \cdot \mathbf v} {\left\lVert \mathbf v^2 \right\rVert} \right) \mathbf v = \left( \frac {\mathbf a \cdot \mathbf v} {\left\lVert \mathbf v \right\rVert} \right)$$
And why does all the documentation go by the first rather than the second proof?

Comment: Your definition does not give the direction of the vector. It is a scalar.

Answer (score 1):

The projection, also known as the "resolved part", of vector $\underline{a}$ onto vector $\underline{v}$ is the **component** of $\underline{a}$ in the direction of $\underline{v}$ and is therefore a **scalar** quantity, not a vector quantity.

It is correctly given by the formula you gave: $$\frac{\underline{a}\cdot\underline{v}}{|\underline{v}|}$$